# Regex to find non-alphanumeric symbols wrapped into certain XML tags

Tags: regex

Hello everyone.

I faced a little problem with Regular Expressions.

I have a lot of XML files and I need to create a regex expression to find all instances of the following pattern:

```
<text styleclass="" style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt; color:#000000;">).</text>
```

In other words, I need to find each case when `).` are wrapped with the <text> tag. Attributes in the opeining <text> tag may vary.

Here are some sample sentences to play with:

```
<para styleclass="Normal">Password validity period specified in days (the <text styleclass="T_UIcontrol">Passport expiration check</text> parameter value is set to <text styleclass="T_Option">true</text> <text styleclass="" style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt; color:#000000;">).</text></para>
<para styleclass="Normal">Password validity period specified in days (the <text styleclass="T_UIcontrol">Passport expiration check</text> parameter value is set to false <text styleclass="" style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt; color:#000000;">).</text></para>
```

The best I came up with is `(?<=(<\/text>.))(<text.*>)(?=\)\.<\/text>)(\)\.<\/text>)`, but in only works for the first sentence.

Can you give me any ideas or code samples to help creating an ultimate regex expression that will suitable for any cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
<text[^>]*>\)\.</text>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm. I have never expected the answer to be this easy!